# How can I create a new table in Power BI from three columns of another table with a filter?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with repeating values ​​in the index column, and a third column that has values ​​only in some rows

Table I have now:

[image: Table I have now]

My objective is to create a new table that selects the CompanyID, Start Date, and Contact Date columns but excludes the rows that have blank values from any of those

New table I want to have:

[image: New table I want to have]

I used the following DAX code:

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    Table,
    FILTER ( Table, NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Start Date] ) ) )
)
```

The issue with this code is that it selects all 350+ columns of my original data instead of just having the 3 columns I want. Additionally, I couldn't figure out how to add additional filters so I don't have blank rows for Contact Date and ComapanyID

I did try the below code as well, but it doesn't work

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    Table,
    FILTER ( Table, NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Start Date] ) ) ),
    FILTER ( Table, NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Order Date] ) ) ),
    FILTER ( Table, NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Employee Count] ) ) )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The SELECTCOLUMNS function allows you to pick specific columns.

For example:

```
New Filtered Table =
EVALUATE
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        Table,
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Start Date] ) ),
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Order Date] ) ),
        NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[Employee Count] ) )
    ),
    "CompanyID", Table[CompanyID],
    "Contact Date", Table[Contact Date],
    "Start Date", Table[Start Date]
)
```

Comment: If the primary key "CompanyID" is duplicated, with multiple rows, would I need a merge query or a join to get the values scattered throughout the original table in line with one another? i.e. 123 - 1/1/2020 - 2/1/2020 - 390. It seems that if I just select the columns that aren't blank, there will be no rows at all, as there are no rows in the original table where the data is in each column. Each row has blanks, and no row is without blanks

Comment: I suggest you edit your question then as it's not at all apparent from what you've shown that all rows have some blanks.